# Configuring the DataSource jndi name in openejb to JBoss specific

Tags: unit-testing, openejb

How to change the JNDI name (**java:/openejb/Resource/MysqlDS**) in the **OpenEJB embedded Container** to suite JBoss specific (**java:/MysqlDS**) in a Testcase for unit testing. 
 Can this be configured in Resource injection of DataSource?

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can change the JNDI name template using `openejb.jndiname.format` property. See [embedded configuration](http://openejb.apache.org/embedded-configuration.html) for an example and [Jndi-names](http://openejb.staging.apache.org/jndi-names.html) for the supported templates.

Comment: openejb.jndiname.format is used to format the jndi names for the EJBs and is it applicable for changing the jndi for  Resources like Datasources, JMS.. etc., ?